# Show Word AutoRecover Window

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, interop, recovery

Is there a way to enable/create the MS Word AutoRecovery Pane automatically? In the case of unsaved documents Word opens the AutoRecovery Pane within the first Word process. If I start a second Word process, the Recovery Window is not shown anymore.

I'm able to handle the visibily for the first Wordprocess with following code:

```
WordApp.Application.CommandBars["Document Recovery"].Visible = false;
WordApp.Application.CommandBars["Document Recovery"].Enabled = false;
```

But any other Wordprocess dont provide the "Document Recovery" CommandBar. I'll get a "Argument was out of the range of valid values" Exception.

Any ideas to show the Document Recovery window on every Wordprocess?

Answer (score 0):

CommandBars were deprecated. Use the [ActivePane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.window.activepane) property of the `Window` class instead:

```
ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.Close
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to get the "Document Recover" Pane. When I start Word with an emtpy document (and unsaved documents to recover), there is only one active pane availabe and I guess it is the actual Word document.